# Issue with cloning a parent Item that has 50+ children

Tags: apex, clone

In the below function, the line `Item__c newIt = it.clone(false,true,false,false);` throws an error `System.QueryException: Aggregate query has too many rows for direct assignment, use FOR loop`.

This only happens when this Item has more than 50+ child SKUs(SKU is a child object). If it has 30-40 child SKUs i am not getting that error. Please help me out with this issue.

```
private static void getItems(Id oldOpportunityID, Id newOpportunityID) {
    Map<String,String> itemMap = new Map<String,String>();
    List<String> newItemList = new List<String>();
    String newItemStr = '';
    List<String> newSKUist = new List<String>();
    String emptyItemID = '';
    Map<Id,List<SKU__c>> itemSku = new Map<Id,List<SKU__c>>();

    Map<String,Schema.SObjectField> itemSObject = Schema.SObjectType.Item__c.fields.getMap();

    String itemQuery = 'SELECT ';
    Integer i = 0;
    for (String s : itemSObject.keySet()) { //Also get the SKUs related and URLS Releated
        if (i > 0) {
            itemQuery += ', ' + s;
        } else {
            itemQuery += s;
            i++;
        }

    }

    Map <String, Schema.SObjectType> schemaMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
    Schema.DescribeSObjectResult R = Item__c.SObjectType.getDescribe();
    List<Schema.ChildRelationship> C = R.getChildRelationships();

    for (Schema.ChildRelationship cr : C){
        if (cr.getRelationshipName() == 'SKUs__r') {
            Schema.SObjectType childObject = cr.getChildSObject();
            String objName = String.valueOf(childObject);
            Map <String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = schemaMap.get(objName).getDescribe().fields.getMap();
            List<string> FieldsList = new List<string>();
            integer j = 0;
            for(Schema.SObjectField sfield : fieldMap.Values())
            {
                i++;
                schema.describefieldresult dfield = sfield.getDescribe();
                FieldsList.add(dfield.getname());
                if (j > 0) {
                    itemQuery += ', ' + dfield.getname();
                } else {
                    itemQuery += ', (SELECT ' + dfield.getname();
                        j++;    
                    }
                }

                itemQuery += ' FROM ' + cr.getRelationshipName() + ')';
        }

    }

    itemQuery += ' FROM Item__c WHERE Opportunity__c = ' + '\'' + oldOpportunityID + '\'' ;
    List<Item__c> deepClonedList = new List<Item__c>();
    System.debug(itemQuery);


    List<sObject> itemList = Database.query(itemQuery);

    for (sObject obj : itemList) {
        Item__c it = (Item__c) obj;
        ***Item__c newIt = it.clone(false,true,false,false);***
        List<SKU__c>  skew = it.SKUs__r;
        itemSku.put(it.id,skew);//Map                       ItemSKU   old_item_id,list_of_skus
        newIt.Merchantry_External_Item_ID__c = '';

        newIt.Opportunity__c = newOpportunityID;

        itemMap.put(it.id,newIt.Merchantry_Item_ID__c);//Map ItemMap   old_item_id,new_external_id
        system.debug('Old Item Id:'+it.Id+'New External id:'+newIt.Merchantry_Item_ID__c);

        deepClonedList.add(newIt);
    }
```

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that you're getting this error on the line where you clone the Item__c record, and not on a few lines above where you are running your dynamic query?

Comment: I'm with @DerekF here - the error message tells you to recode `List<sObject> itemList = Database.query(itemQuery);` as `for (sObject obj :  Database.query(itemQuery)) {...}` - see https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_group_by_considerations.htm?search_text=limits

Comment: @crop1645 Some additional information. When I reproduced this in one of my sandboxes (Winter '16) through anonymous apex, I did stick the dynamic query into a loop and added the records to a `Map<Id, sObject>`. After that, when I looped through that `Map<Id, sObject>`, I also encountered this error (aggregate query has too many rows...) when attempting to cast the current sObject from the map back to a concrete sObject. 250 records in the parent-child aggregate query was the threshold for me, irrespective of the number of fields I was querying for on the child object.

Comment: looking at your code - I actually don't see any evidence of an aggregate query (use of an aggregate function or group by) - but I may have missed it.  Instead, it looks like you are trying to generate a relationship query. Edit your post with an example of the generated query that fails  (feel free to use ellipsis to avoid it being too long)

Comment: @crop1645 The parent-child subquery in the `SELECT` statement of a SOQL query is an 'Aggregate Query`...even though it doesn't use any aggregate functions/group by.

Comment: @DerekF thank you for the reply..but the line is said is the problem and SF does throw that error when there is a parent-child relationship involved not just when the aggregate functions are involved... I need some plan to reprogram that part

Comment: @DerekF can u send me the modified code u wrote

Comment: @DerekF - I had a somewhat related issue documented here - http://cropredysfdc.com/2015/03/20/invalid-query-locator/  -- wherein the number of child records caused the query to fail - even within a for loop - and the only solution was two queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few hours of trying to reproduce your error, I haven't been able to reproduce the error with the line of code that you say is generating the error.

Instead of getting the error on the `Item__c newIt = it.clone(false,true,false,false);` line (or rather, the equivalent line in my test code), I am reliably reproducing your error on the line below, `List<SKU__c>  skew = it.SKUs__r;` If you put some `system.debug();` statements above, in between, and below these two lines, you should see that you do get past the cloning in the execution log

Alternatively, you might be able to set some checkpoints via the developer console. (I, myself, haven't managed to get checkpoints to work in the dev console, but it is another option).

Now, to get around this error, you have a few options:

- Do what the error message is suggesting and populate your `List<SKU__c> skew` in a for loop
- In the code you've given us, I don't see you using the related `SKU__c` records anywhere. If you aren't using those records, then it's better to not query them. Thus, you'd avoid this issue altogether
- Break your query into two queries. One to get the `Item__c` records, and another to query the `SKU__c` records

I'll assume that you do need, and use, the `SKU__c` somewhere else in your code. One last thing to note. While `it.clone(false, true, false, false)` is making a deep clone of your `Item__c` records, it is only making a shallow copy of the related `SKU__c` records.

If you simply try to stick `it.SKUs__r` into a loop, you'll probably get an 'Invalid query locator' error. To get around -that-, you just need to put your `database.query()` into the for loop itself (rather than into an intermediate list, and then using that list in the for loop)

```
for (sObject obj : Database.query(itemQuery)) {
    Item__c it = (Item__c) obj;
    Item__c newIt = it.clone(false,true,false,false);
    List<SKU__c>  skew = new List<SKU__c>();
    for(sObject obj2 : it.SKUs__r){
        skew.add((SKU__c)obj2);
    }
    itemSku.put(it.id,skew);//Map                       ItemSKU   old_item_id,list_of_skus
    newIt.Merchantry_External_Item_ID__c = '';

    newIt.Opportunity__c = newOpportunityID;

    itemMap.put(it.id,newIt.Merchantry_Item_ID__c);//Map ItemMap   old_item_id,new_external_id
    system.debug('Old Item Id:'+it.Id+'New External id:'+newIt.Merchantry_Item_ID__c);

    deepClonedList.add(newIt);
}
```

Comment: Your above comment worked but with a limitation of 250... 
"When I reproduced this in one of my sandboxes through anonymous apex, I did stick the dynamic query into a loop and added the records to a Map<Id, sObject>. After that, when I looped through that Map<Id, sObject>, I also encountered this error (aggregate query has too many rows...) when attempting to cast the current sObject from the map back to a concrete sObject. 250 records in the parent-child aggregate query was the threshold for me, irrespective of the number of fields I was querying for on the child object."